# vertx class cast exception

Tags: json, vert.x

I'm doing a POST specified in the Swagger as follow:

```
    post:
      tags:
        - entries
      summary: Add an entry to the phonebook
      operationId: addEntry
      produces:
        - application/json
      consumes:
        - application/json
      parameters:
       - in: body
         name: newEntry
         schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Entry"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
        '400':
          description: Invalid Entry input
```

the Entry definition being:

```
definitions:
  Entry:
    type: object
    properties:
      firstName:
        type: string
      lastName:
        type: string
      phoneNumber:
        type: string
```

The POST request body look as follow:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "phoneNumber": "0123456789"
}
```

This request is handled by a verticle in the following section:

```java
vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject> consumer(ADDENTRYBYID_SERVICE_ID)
.handler(message -> {
  try {
    Phonebook.Entry newEntry = Json.mapper.readValue(message.body().getJsonObject("newEntry").encode(), Phonebook.Entry.class);
} 
..
}
```

This call fails with the following exception:

```java
java.lang.String cannot be cast to io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject
```

when the cast `(JsonObject)val` is made.

Indeed, val is a `String` (with value equals to the JSON request body above) , and it can't obviously be casted to a JsonObject.

Rewriting the handler as follow:

```java
vertx.eventBus().<String> consumer(ADDENTRYBYID_SERVICE_ID)
.handler(message -> {
  try {
    Phonebook.Entry newEntry = Json.mapper.readValue(message.body(), Phonebook.Entry.class);
} 
..
}
```

would also lead to a class cast exception:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

These exceptions are thrown by the code below:

```java
  public JsonObject getJsonObject(String key) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(key);
    Object val = map.get(key);
    if (val instanceof Map) {
      val = new JsonObject((Map)val);
    }
    return (JsonObject)val;
  }
```

Strangely, `message.body()`IS a `JsonObject` instance.

***Note***: `JsonObject` is a vertx implementation (`io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`)

**Questions**

1. Why val is a `String` here ?
2. How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

No ideas why, it work now (???) with the initial code:

```java
vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject> consumer(ADDENTRYBYID_SERVICE_ID).handler(message -> {
    try {
        Phonebook.Entry newEntry = Json.mapper.readValue(message.body().getJsonObject("newEntry").encode(), Phonebook.Entry.class);
    }
...
}
```